# Multiple ASP.NET DropDownLists are being set to the same value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 6 dropdown lists (with identical options), and I am manually setting them in my codebehind. All six should have different values. When I log the values I am setting them to, I get the correct assumed values to be set to. However, when the page renders, all six of them are set to the same freaking value.

I have tried setting the values with all of the following:

```
// set index, find by text

dd1.SelectedIndex = dd1.Items.IndexOf(dd1.Items.FindByText(val1));

// set with selected value

dd2.SelectedValue = val2;

// set index, find by value

dd3.SelectedIndex = dd3.Items.IndexOf(dd3.Items.FindByValue(val3));

// set list item, selected = true

((ListItem)dd4.Items.FindByValue(val4)).Selected = true;
```

The dropdown lists' set of options are generated prior to me trying to set them:

```
foreach (Station st in stations) {
ListItem li = new ListItem() { Text = st.fromto, Value = st.fromto};
dd1.Items.Add(li); 
dd2.Items.Add(li); 
dd3.Items.Add(li); 
dd4.Items.Add(li); 
dd5.Items.Add(li); 
dd6.Items.Add(li); 
}
```

I then look in the database to see if any values exist for a specific reference id in my app. If so, it indicates that I need to set one or more (up to 6) dropdowns:

```
var existingStations = db.LOGOPS_STATIONs.Where(x => x.XREF_LOGOP_MAIN_ID == logopRefId);
    if (existingStations.Count() > 0) {
        int i = 1;
        foreach (LOGOPS_STATION s in existingStations) {
            if (i < 7) {
                string text= s.FROM_STATION;

                    if (i == 1) dd1.SelectedIndex = dd1.Items.IndexOf(dd1.Items.FindByText(text));
                     // for the heck of it, set the next one manually...                            
                     else if (i == 2) dd2.SelectedIndex = 2;
                             // try and set one with forcing select
                     else if (i == 3) ((ListItem)dd3.Items.FindByText(text)).Selected = true;
                             // good ol normal
                     else if (i == 4) dd4.SelectedValue = text;
                    ... and so on ...

            }
        }
    }
```

So, the dropdowns are all populated (when I log in the codebehind they're fully populated). And when I log the actual values when they're being set, they're set to the value as expected. However, when the page loads, they're all set to the same thing

At any rate, not sure what else to do. I have turned on and off different event validation hookups. I have disabled all JS to see if that was manipulating values, and it's not. I have tried explicitly setting like this

```
dd1.SelectedIndex = 2;

dd2.SelectedIndex = 8;
```

Oddly enough, that doesn't work either. For real, when does setting SelectedIndex to a unique control with a unique id not set the item?

Comment: During which event are you trying to set the values? Can we see some of relevant code from your aspx page? Are they actually all being set to the last value to try to set to one of them or are they all being set to a default value or some other value?

Comment: We probably need more thorough info to work with.  For example, where are you performing these "SelectedIndex =" operations? Page_Init?  Page_Load?  Constructor?  Is the problem occurring the first time you hit the page, postbacks, or both?  Where in the code are you defining the selection lists and their contents/options?  In the ASPX page, or in the codebehind?  If the latter, where/when?

Comment: It sounds like you might be setting the value before the list is bound to the datasource. Can you include the code that shows how the controls are databound, and maybe some details about the datasource.

Comment: Which item is being selected? The last item added to the dropdowns, or the item you explicitly select last in your code? We need some more information about the problem really.

Comment: #1 --> if !isPostBack, then I run a method that first of all clears all of the dropdowns, then repopulates, then if data is present, sets the dropdowns to those values

Comment: #2 --> initiated via page_load.. i'll edit the original post to include this

Comment: #3 --> option lists are composed and applied to the control before I ever attempt to set the value.. i'll edit original post to include this

Comment: #4 --> I posted more code: the items are being selected explicitly in the codebehind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create a separate list item for each dropdown instead of them all sharing the same li in the foreach loop. And then a step further, had to set Selected = false in the constructor of the ListItem

I assumed that you could 'reuse' code for each instance of the dropdown population, but each dropdown needed it's own unique ListItem

Maybe there's a better way, but this solution seems to have solved the problem